# aws codebuild failed in DOWNLOAD_SOURCE

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild, aws-ecs

I trying to run codebuild using my docker image for a build .Net framework application,
but when i run the project it's failed in "[DOWNLOAD_SOURCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6oRS.jpg)" step with the message:
**"Build container found dead before completing the build. Build container died because it was out of memory, or the Docker image is not supported."**

the source is codecommit .
Compute type is 15 GB .
docker image is the same as docker image here: [https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments-for-the-net-framework/]
I've tried the same image with a lightweight project and it's work.

Any suggestions?
there is a way to get more logs?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your image needs more memory than you have

Comment: more than 15 GB memory? or you mean the docker image( i didn't use memory limit in my build )

Comment: No, but docker has a default memory reservation. If you did `docker run` you could add option `--memory-reservation=8g`, because default are 2Gb. Maybe you should try to look up equivalent for AWS platform or where configure it.

Comment: i using windows server and windows doesn't support memory reservation :(

Answer (score 0):

did you try setting the git-clone-depth to 1 to do a shallow clone? since the same image worked for a lightweight project.

Comment: git clone depth setting to 1, but it still not working